# The collapsed Bootstrap navbar doesn't open when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

What I'm trying to do is to make the navbar collapse when it's on a smaller screen and make it expand when a button is clicked.
But when I click the button nothing happens and I have no idea why.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="images\logo1.png" width="200" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-nav dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Behandelingen
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="sportmassage.html">Sportmassage</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="massagetherapie.html">Massagetherapie</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="ontspanningsmassage.html">Ontspanningsmassage</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="tarieven.html">Tarieven</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent"` on your toggle button is wrong. It should match the id of `.navbar-collapse`.

Read more about Bootstrap 4's collapse via `data-` attribute [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/#via-data-attributes)

Comment: Thank you this helped me out a lot.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Your issue:

The `data-target` attribute of the `<button class="navbar-toggler">` and the `id` of the `<div class="navbar-collapse">` need to match for this functionality to work (the `data-target` beginning with a hashtag to refer to the id).

---

**Sample:**

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#collapseElement" aria-controls="collapseElement"></button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseElement">
```

---

**This is a minimal working example which isolates just the elements related to the topic:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    Nagivation Elements Here
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

The `aria-controls` attribute is also supposed to match, though this particular functionality seems to work without it.

**Here is the full working code:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">

  <!-- This button is the navbar-toggler. This data-target refers to the id of the .navbar-collapse element -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <!-- This div is the collapsable element -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="images\logo1.png" width="200" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-nav dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Behandelingen
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="sportmassage.html">Sportmassage</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="massagetherapie.html">Massagetherapie</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="ontspanningsmassage.html">Ontspanningsmassage</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="tarieven.html">Tarieven</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In practice, be sure to always include your links to your stylesheets at the top of the page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle `data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"` changed then work. Hope this help you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="images\logo1.png" width="200" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-nav dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Behandelingen
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="sportmassage.html">Sportmassage</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="massagetherapie.html">Massagetherapie</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="ontspanningsmassage.html">Ontspanningsmassage</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="tarieven.html">Tarieven</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

## please make sure your id

> data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent"

**and**

> id="navbarToggleExternalContent">

## should same to same

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="images\logo1.png" width="200" height="80" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-nav dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Behandelingen
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="sportmassage.html">Sportmassage</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="massagetherapie.html">Massagetherapie</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="ontspanningsmassage.html">Ontspanningsmassage</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="tarieven.html">Tarieven</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```